# how to create full screen notification in flutter

Tags: flutter, notifications, dialog, screen, payload

I want to create full screen dialog in flutter when notification came from app. So full screen notification payload without click notification. I want to make it automatic redirect or notification dialog screen but it should overlay the lock screen.

Now I have only notification popup dialog at the time. **But disappears among other notifications and I don't want notifications to be overlooked.**

- I am using dependency : flutter_local_notifications: ^9.7.0

**Here is my notification schedule method**

```
void scheduleTaskNotification(Task task) async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channelId',
      'channelName',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );

    /*NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails,
    );*/

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
         task.id!,
         task.title,
         task.note,
         _convertTime(int.parse(task.startTime.toString().split(':')[0]), int.parse(task.startTime.toString().split(':')[1])),
         //tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
         NotificationDetails(
             android: androidNotificationDetails,),
         androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
         uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
             UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
             matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
             payload: '${task.title} | ${task.note} |');
  }
```

**Help me about it. I am posting sample screen below that i want to create.**

[Sample screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cO9Sx.png)

**I want to show this screen programmatically when notification came.**
[image: Flutter notification screen example]

Comment: Still no. I created a dialog that triggers when the notification is clicked, but I couldn't create a self-triggered dialog. But I did not try to create a big notification screen. Maybe

Comment: Did you try full-screen-intent-notifications?I think that's what you are looking for 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications#full-screen-intent-notifications